# Error occurs when coming back from subroutine of fortran by numpy.f2py

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I made hoge as simple as possible and errors still coming.
Please tell me what problems are.

This is my Fortran subroutine code.

```
subroutine hoge(d)
  complex(kind(0d0)), intent(out):: d(5,10,15) ! 5 10 15 does not have special meanings..

  ! these two lines works..
  ! integer, parameter :: dp = kind(0d0)
  ! complex(dp), intent(out) :: d(5,10,15)

  do i=1,15
    do j=1,10
      do k=1,5
        d(k,j,i)=0
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo
  ! instead 
  ! d(1:5,1:10,1:15)=0 or
  ! d(:,:,:)=0 also brings the error.
  !
  print*,'returning'
  return
end subroutine hoge
```

I want to use a Fortran subroutine. I compiled like below

```
python -m numpy.f2py -c hoge.f90 -m hoge
```

and use as below

```
import hoge
hoge.hoge()
```

then the result is the three lines below:

```
Returning
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I totally have no idea... please tell me what problems are.

When the line has a change like below

```
do j=1,10   -> do j=1,5
```

the error does not occur... (for your information..)
1..6 brings the error.

Comment: Looks like you call in pythonn the function without argument and in the fortran subroutine you expect an array (the directive `intent(out)` just says that the content should / will be set in the subroutine). Still a strange message but maybe a pointer.

Comment: A run with d=hoge.hoge() brings the same messages..

Comment: `d` is an argument not a return value of the subroutine. In C terms a subroutine is a void function.

Comment: I also realize that if I make a slight change .. it worked. I updated the question.

Comment: Your updated version is the way to go. Looking at the output of `print(hoge.hoge.__doc__)`, you will see that f2py interprets your original declaration as complex with default floats `d : rank-3 array('F') with bounds (5,10,15)`. However, the alternative declaration gives the desired double result `d : rank-3 array('D') with bounds (5,10,15)`.

Comment: @albert, f2py wraps the Fortran code so that when arguments are declared with `intent(out)` ["The argument is considered as a return variable. It is appended to the <returned variables> list. "](https://numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/signature-file.html#attributes), so in the OP's case, the call in Python is actually correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [F2PY User Guide and Reference Manual](https://numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/advanced.html#dealing-with-kind-specifiers):

> ```
> Currently, F2PY can handle only <type spec>(kind=<kindselector>)
> declarations where <kindselector> is a numeric integer (e.g. 1, 2,
> 4,…), but not a function call KIND(..) or any other expression.
> ```

Thus, the declaration `complex(kind(0d0))` in your code example is exactly the kind of *function call or other expression* that f2py cannot interpret.

As you have found out (but commented out in the code), one work around is to first generate an integer kind specifier (`integer, parameter :: dp = kind(0d0)`), and then use that in the kind specifier of your complex variable `complex(dp)`.

If changing the Fortran source code like this is not an option for you, the documentation further outlines how a *mapping file* (with default name `.f2py_f2cmap` or passed using command line flag `--f2cmap <filename>`) can be created and used instead. In your case, you can e.g. use the default file with the following contents:

```
$ cat .f2py_f2cmap
{'complex': {'KIND(0D0)': 'complex_double'}}
```

and compile as before, to get the desired behaviour.