# Why does f2py say that an iso_fortran_env value does not reduce to a constant expression?

Tags: fortran, f2py

I can compile the following code just fine using `gfortran -c test.f90`.

```
module math
    contains
    function addition(a, b) result(f)
        use iso_fortran_env, only: REAL64
        implicit none
        real(REAL64), intent(in) :: a, b
        real(REAL64) :: f
        f = a + b
    end function
end module
```

I use f2py

```
python -m numpy.f2py -c test.f90 -m test
```

and I get the following error

```
/tmp/tmpJLxRSe/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/test-f2pywrappers2.f90:7:16:

       real(kind=real64) a
                1
Error: Parameter ‘real64’ at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
```

I have verified that I can successfully use `selected_real_kind(15,307)`, as suggested in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523524/f2py-specifying-real-precision-in-fortran-when-interfacing-with-python?rq=1). However, I was interested in using iso_fortran_env, if possible.

Comment: The error message you show does not match the code.  Try posting the code that actually corresponds to error?

Comment: I used copy and paste for the code above.  If it helps I am using gfortran 7.5.0 and numpy 1.13.3.

Comment: Also try `use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : real64` to be clear you want the intrinsic module.

Comment: @francescalus Thank you for the suggestion to include the intrinsic keyword.  I tried it and verified that it compiles fine when not using f2py.  However, I get the same error message as above when using f2py.

Comment: f2py does not work well with modern Fortran.

Comment: As Vladimir F says, it's a limitation of f2py, but there is a workaround, see e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61869003/3967096

Comment: You did not show the code that gfortran is trying to compile.  You are showing an error message for code that python has mutilated.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to just use `real(8)` or `real*8` as long as you are using `gfortran` or `ifort` with `F2PY`.

Alternatively, as mentioned for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523524/f2py-specifying-real-precision-in-fortran-when-interfacing-with-python) you could possibly solve it by making a file `.f2py_f2cmap` with the content:

```
dict(real=dict(REAL64='double'))
```

But anyway the iso_fortran_env is then not relevant anymore. An alternative is to call the real code from a simplified fortran subroutine that has only `real(8)` definitions.