# What shall be used in Modern Fortran to specify a 8 bytes real variable if iso_fortran_env is not supported?

Tags: fortran, f2py

I want to specify as type of a subroutine a floating point value (real) of 8 bytes precision.

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520819/what-does-real8-mean) that the modern way to do it would be:

```
real(real64), intent(out)       :: price_open(length)
```

However, `iso_fortran_env` is not supported by `f2py` (same as it does not support `iso_c_bindings` either).

I get errors of this type:

```
   94 |       real(kind=real64) price_open(length)
      |                1
Error: Parameter 'real64' at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
```

The link referenced before states that using kind would be the proper way if `iso_fortran_env` is not available and that `real*8` shall be avoided.

- I have been using `real(8)` is that equivalent to using kinds? If not, what shall I use?
- What is wrong with `real*8` if I want to always enforce 8 bytes floating point values?

Comment: Is it specifically the 8-bytes container that is of interest, or 64-bit precision? If it is the latter, you could use [`selected_real_kind()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SELECTED_005fREAL_005fKIND.html) intrinsic.

Comment: Could you elaborate on differences? I thought it was the same.

Comment: You might be interested in my thoughts on the subject: https://stevelionel.com/drfortran/2017/03/27/doctor-fortran-in-it-takes-all-kinds/

Comment: Thanks Steve, I read it twice. Still some practical doubts that I will share here just in case somebody wants to comment. King states about the difference between an 8 bytes container and 64 bit precision. First doubt I have is that I thought precision for floating point numbers was specified in terms of decimal places and not in terms of bits.

Comment: The second doubt I have is that, I am specifically looking for interoperability with C, specifically I am looking for having a `double` and while the C standard does not define its size (or format IIRC) in the practical real world of 2021 that always defaults to `8 bytes` in today's 64 bits servers. That suffices me and I do not need further portability. In that case, and given that `f2py` does not support `iso_c_bindings` or `iso_fortran_env`, I am still wondering what shall I be using. I am still unclear on that even after reading Steve's article (which it is worth reading for sure).

Comment: Regarding f2py, by manually specifying a mapping, it is possible to write standard conforming Fortran code with e.g. iso-c-binding (or other kind specifiers), that can be interpreted by f2py. See e.g: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61869003

Comment: @M.E. I do not mean in any way to discourage the use of f2py by the following statement, only to report a personal experience. With the `iso_c_binding` of F2003 and `ctypes` module of Python, I don't see the need for `f2py` in almost any use case. I personally frequently find the former easier to implement, maintain, and use than the latter.

Comment: Does `ctypes` return numpy arrays from C arrays and the opposite (you pass a numpy array to a C function expecting a C array)? I am interested in exploring alternatives to f2py

Comment: @M.E. C takes a pointer to the array and returns a pointer to the array. So as long as you use the returned array with appropriate bounds, numpy has not problems dealing with it.

Comment: @King, I am trying to get it converted into a numpy array in case yo want to contribute also to that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68513850/how-do-i-convert-a-pointer-returned-by-a-c-function-invoked-using-ctypes-into-a

Answer (score 3):

You say you are *specifically* interested in interoperability with C. However, `iso_c_binding`, nor `iso_fortran_env` are supported. These modules have constants that help you to set the right kind constant for a given purpose. The one from `iso_fortran_env` would NOT be the right one to choose anyway, it would be `c_double`.

If these constants meant to help you in your choice are not available, you are on your own. Now you can choose any other method freely.

It is completely legitimate to use just `kind(1.d0)` and just check that the connection to C works. Automake had been doing that for ages.

Or use `selected_real_kind()`, it does not matter, it is really up to you. Just check that `double` in C ended up being the same numeric type.

The traditional thing in automatic build processes was to do many tests about which (mainly C) constant ended up having which value. You just need to check that double precision in Fortran does indeed correspond to double in C. It is very likely, but just check it. You can have a macro that changes the choice if not, but probably it is a needless work untill you actually meet such a system.